# JS window.location() not working for Android Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am executing a JS where I want to redirect to a page using window.location() method. However this method is working absolutely fine with other Browsers (Mobile / Desktop) but there's an exception with Chrome Browser (Android Version) that this method is not being executed. 
Moreover when I use this method like setTimeout(window.location(), 10), the page is successfully redirected even in Android Chrome Browser.

Here's my JS:

```
function Redirect() {
    if ('@Html.Raw(Model)'.indexOf(window.location.protocol) != -1) {
        window.location = '@Html.Raw(Model)';
    } else {
        var origin = window.location.origin || (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host);
        window.location.href = origin + '@Html.Raw(Model)';
    }
}
setTimeout('Redirect()', 10);
```

Comment: `window.location` should be `window.location.href`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Redirect() {
    if ('@Html.Raw(Model)'.indexOf(window.location.protocol) != -1) {
        window.location.href = '@Html.Raw(Model)';
    } else {
        var origin = window.location.origin || (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host);
        window.location.href = origin + '@Html.Raw(Model)';
    }
}
setTimeout('Redirect()', 10);
```